# Facing the issue that Xcode cannot run successfully for the code part and got activate to disable on AWS site as well

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, amazon-sns

I want to implement IOS Amazon SNS push notification.
I followed the tutorial here

https://medium.com/@thabodavidnyakalloklass/ios-push-with-amazons-aws-simple-notifications-service-sns-and-swift-made-easy-51d6c79bc206

However I faced the two issues:
1. I cannot run code on Xcode: 
the images here:[IMG1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icEe3.png)
[IMG2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vruhy.png)
2. On the Amazon SNS web console part: 
 After a few seconds, the status changes from "active" to "disabled"
[IMG3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27fB8.png)

Please help me out. Thank you so much and I appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please bear in mind that it is a good practice to embed files directly into the question or providing code samples. This is due to two reasons : it is more readable for viewers and unfortunately files tend to disappear from making the question not understandable for future readers.

Comment: Could you please instruct me how to embed the image into question rather than a link? Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, please refer to this question on StackExchange Meta : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post. If you are unable to embed it due to too low reputation, write it in the comment and then me or other readers will be able to edit your question to embed pictures in the post.